# Getting the upper bound of a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the upperbound value of a string in ASP.NET MVC. At the moment, we have a bunch of file paths in a database with a file name for the file part, and we only want to display for the filename. IE, rather than `http://intranet/level1/level2/level3/level4/filename.pdf` for example, we just want filename `.pdf` - In ASP we used `UBound`, is this the same as Upperbound? At the moment, it goes to 10 spaces, but this could be more or less in future. Getting the upperbound and printing it is giving "10", rather than `filename.pdf` is there a way to get the value?

The code is as follows:

```
        <td>
        @{
var TheLink = item.BulletinFile;
var TheSplit = TheLink.Split('/');
var SplitName = TheSplit.GetUpperBound(0);
        }
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BulletinFile)

    </td>
```

Comment: `.pdf` is not the filename.

Comment: I know, "filename.pdf" is an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only the file-name use the `Path`-class, especially [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string url = "http://intranet/level1/level2/level3/level4/filename.pdf";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(url); // filename.pdf
```

Just to answer the question how it was asked, you *could* use `String.Split`:

```
string fileName = url.Split('/').Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string you can use

```
var lastdot = text.LastIndexOf('.');
var lastslash = text.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
string s = text.Substring(lastslash,lastdot- lastslash );
```